# Why was this question closed by 1 person?

Tags: discussion

[Is it normal to reject a peer-reviewed paper and then reject it after accepting it without specifying the exact reasons?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/191349/is-it-normal-to-reject-a-peer-reviewed-paper-and-then-reject-it-after-accepting)

Usually, you need 4, but a moderator was quick to close the question. I just want to know if it is at all unusual to reject a peer-reviewed paper after accepting it. How can I change the question to prevent a moderator for closing it without any good reason?

Comment: I commented why I closed it. What was unclear about the comment?

Comment: I think @Mark's [comment](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/191349/is-it-normal-to-reject-a-peer-reviewed-paper-and-then-reject-it-after-accepting#comment516468_191349) pretty much answered your question. Only the journal editors and reviewers can give you further explanations.

Comment: Note that a high rep user with appropriate gold "tag" badges can also close some questions on their own, especially those that are duplicates. Mods of course have the power always. You can also flag your own closed question and request a review. Or edit it to respond to the reason for closing.

Answer (score 4):

> I just want to know if it is at all unusual to reject a peer-reviewed paper after accepting it.

I think you know the answer to this question, which is that it is unusual.
The interesting question is of course whether this unusual procedure is justified, which is nothing we can answer as it requires dissecting the specific issue at hand and information not available to us.

Also, if this is what you wanted to know, you could have simply written that and only referenced the specific issue as an aside.
Instead you wrote things like:

> I am thinking it's a bogus excuse and it's because of political reasons only

Whether intentional or not, this invites discussions about the contents of the paper and its political implications.

I don’t see a question related to this issue that is neither trivial (i.e., we all know the answer) nor opinion-based, off-topic or otherwise unsuitable for this site.

Comment: *The interesting question is of course whether this unusual procedure is justified* We really should answer the question that is asked, not the question we think is being asked.

Comment: @Allure: I wasn’t contesting this. But we need to take into account that most people answer the question they think is being asked, even when the asker takes extra care to point out what their question is not about. If a question is particularly prone to attracting answers that do not answer the explicit question (e.g., by large digressions or strong claims about something else), that is something that needs to be fixed. And if the explicit question is probably not the one that the asker wants to ask, then it’s best to close, so things can be clarified before anybody answers.

Comment: In that case I'd argue that the problem is the answer, not the question. *if the explicit question is probably not the one that the asker wants to ask* This is also not something for others to comment on. If the question is not what the asker wanted to ask, it's still the question that should be answered, and if the asker wants to ask something else then they can edit their question.

Comment: *In that case I'd argue that the problem is the answer, not the question.* – And …? Closing prevents answers and thus prevents problems. A singular non-answer can be deleted, but if a question is prone to attracting non-answers, we deleting all of them would be a major disturbance (particularly if people upvote them because they are accurate despite not answering the explicit question).

Comment: The asker didn't cause the problem, the answerer did, but you are blaming the asker. I don't see why you don't seem to think that's a problem - it's similar to victim blaming.

Comment: *This is also not something for others to comment on.* – I strongly disagree. If you have a reasonable suspicion that you (or others) misunderstand somebody’s communication, the only ethical thing is to seek to clarify this, ideally before more confusion arises further down the line. Think about how you would communicate outside the Internet.

Comment: Sure, but then you ask "are you sure you are asking X question instead of Y question", instead of (as Bryan Kreuse wrote) "This question appears to be about Y instead of X".

Comment: *The asker didn't cause the problem, the answerer did, but you are blaming the asker. […]* – This seems to boil down to the conception that closure is a punishment/blame for the asker. While I understand where this conception comes from, it is not a basis we can operate on. Closing simply means that answers to the question are prevented. Most questions we closed are not asked with bad intentions. Often there is some degree of neglecting guidance involved, but at times there isn’t. (Mind that in this particular case, I won’t put zero blame on the asker as outlined in this answer.)